# Coins problem in Erlang

Tags: combinatorics, erlang

How many different ways can 200 be made using any number of coins? The possible denominations are 1, 2, 5, 10, 20, 50, 100, 200.

```
-module(coins).
-export([coins/2]).


coins(_, 0) -> 1;
coins([], _) -> 0;
coins(_, Goal) when Goal < 0 -> 0;
coins([H|T], Goal) ->
  coins([H|T], Goal-H) + coins(T, Goal).
```

The call is:

```
1> c(coins).
2> coins:coins([1, 2, 5, 10, 20, 50, 100, 200], 200).
73682
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily give more structure to your code:

```
-module(coins).
-export([coins/2]).

-spec coins([CoinValue::integer()], Goal::integer()) -> Combinations::integer().

coins(_, 0) -> 1;
coins([], _) -> 0;
coins(_, Goal) when Goal < 0 -> 0;
coins([CoinValue|Rest], Goal) ->
  WithCoinValue = coins([H|T], Goal-H),
  WithoutCoinValue = coins(T, Goal),
  WithCoinValue + WithoutCoinValue.
```

Comment: Thanks for the `spec` . About new variables(WithCoinValue, WithoutCoinValue) IMHO, they are spare. But this is a question of taste